# create super column and key

Tags: cassandra

I not too familiar with creating a super column. Is `column_type=Super` the right way to assign `Super1` as `super column`?

I could not get the `id` as `index_type: KEYS` to:

```
create column family Super1 with comparator=UTF8Type and 
column_type=Super and key_validation_class=UTF8Type and 
column_metadata = [ 
{column_name: id, validation_class:UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}, 
{column_name: username, validation_class:UTF8Type}, 
{column_name: email, validation_class:UTF8Type}];
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

As found in `\apache-cassandra-0.8.0\conf\schema-sample.txt`:

```
create column family Super1
with column_type = Super
and comparator = BytesType
and subcomparator = BytesType;

create column family Super2
with column_type = Super
and subcomparator = UTF8Type
and rows_cached = 10000
and keys_cached = 50
and comment = 'A column family with supercolumns, whose column and subcolumn names are UTF8 strings';

create column family Super3
with column_type = Super
and comparator = LongType
and comment = 'A column family with supercolumns, whose column names are Longs (8 bytes)';
```

Three different examples to suit your needs...

Answer (score 2):

You can't create column indexes on supercolumns.